# Getting grand totals with grouping sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, grouping-sets

I am migrating SQL SERVER 2005 to SQL SERVER 2014 and came across this problem. I have a "search engine" `STORED PROCEDURE` that builds report queries on the fly for my reporting website. In the old version I used `COMPUTE BY` to get sub totals and grand totals. `COMPUTE BY` is no longer supported in SQL SERVER 2014 and I switched to using `GROUPING SETS`. However, there is a problem. The reports can have more than one page. They can have upwards 200 pages. I only want to show grand total on the last page. By default ever page is fetching 1000 records. The last page would usually show the remaining records and the grand total over the whole record set. I could achieve that with `COMPUTE BY`. With `GROUPING SETS`, I cannot. I can only calculate grand total over the last page only, not the entire record set. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a sample table/sample query/desired result? It's very hard to help without being able to see the problem in action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just use `WITH ROLLUP` and page with `OFFSET`/`FETCH`;

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (id INT, val INT);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4),(4,5);
```

Whole result;

```sql
SELECT id, SUM(val) val FROM test GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN 1 END, id 

id    val
 1     10
 2     15
 3     10
 4     15
 null  50  -- Total sum rollup
```

...and the last page of page size 3;

```sql
SELECT id, SUM(val) val FROM test GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN 1 END, id 
OFFSET 3 ROWS -- skip 3 rows
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY; -- take 3 rows

id    val
 4     15
 null  50  -- Total sum rollup
```

As you see, `WITH ROLLUP` + `OFFSET`/`FETCH` computes over the whole data set, not just the page.

Comment: you don't need *case* here just id is null, id -- if you want to sort it as well